# Atom command not working in terminal

Tags: cygwin, atom-editor

I'm trying to open atom in my current folder but I keep getting this error message:

```
-bash: /cygdrive/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/atom/bin/atom: /bin/sh: 
bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Before that I got this error message:

```
-bash: /cygdrive/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/atom/bin/atom: /bin/sh^M:
bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I used the dos2unix command to try and fix it and ended up with the error message mentioned first.

I'm running cygwin on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Run Atom by clicking on the Atom icon. Once Atom opens, click on the Atom menu and there is a command that says: Install Shell Commands. After you do that you can just type Atom in the terminal and it will launch Atom.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the command worked before, just that it suddenly stopped working. I tried this suggestion but it didn't work unfortunately.